# Use “Check Point” FTP Proxy Authentication Format in WinSCP/SmartFTP

Tags: proxy, ftp, winscp

Can I use "Check Point" FTP Proxy Authentication format in WinSCP or SmartFTP? Basically it's the format like below:

```
USER %u@%s@%h
PASS %p@%w
```

This format is supported in FileZilla. But I need some feature not inside FileZilla, so I have to work with WinSCP or SmartFTP.

Any thought would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Including the log file from WinSCP with the "USER %user@%proxyuser@%host" proxy type:

```
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.362 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.362 WinSCP Version 5.9 (Build 6786) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 - Windows 7 Enterprise)
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.365 Configuration: D:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.ini
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.365 Log level: Normal
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.365 Local account: xxxxxxxxx
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.365 Working directory: D:\Program Files\WinSCP
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.365 Process ID: 9664
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Command-line: "D:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Time zone: Current: GMT+10, Standard: GMT+10 (AUS Eastern Standard Time), DST: GMT+11 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time), DST Start: 2/10/2016, DST End: 3/04/2016
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Login time: Tuesday, 2 August 2016 9:29:59
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Session name: Adobe (Modified site)
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Host name: ftp4.omniture.com (Port: 21)
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 User name: xxxxxxxxx(Password: Yes, Key file: No)
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Transfer Protocol: FTP
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Ping type: Dummy, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Disable Nagle: No
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Proxy: FTP proxy 8
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 HostName: 10.21.160.105 (Port: 8080); Username: xxxxxxxxx; Passwd: Yes
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Send buffer: 262144
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 UTF: Auto
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 FTPS: None [Client certificate: No]
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 FTP: Passive: Yes [Force IP: Auto]; MLSD: Auto [List all: Auto]; HOST: Auto
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Local directory: D:\Data\My Documents, Remote directory: /, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Recycle bin: Delete to: No, Overwritten to: No, Bin path: 
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.368 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.620 Connecting to ftp4.omniture.com ...
. 2016-08-02 09:29:59.620 Connected with 10.21.160.105:8080. Waiting for welcome message...
. 2016-08-02 09:30:14.567 Timeout detected. (control connection)
. 2016-08-02 09:30:14.567 Connection failed.
* 2016-08-02 09:30:14.578 (EFatal) Connection failed.
* 2016-08-02 09:30:14.579 Timeout detected. (control connection)
* 2016-08-02 09:30:14.579 Connection failed.
. 2016-08-02 09:33:11.149 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Couldn't you just input the full 'username@whatever@whatever' in WinSCP's username field?

Comment: Hi Grawity, unfortunately I'm not the system admin. This log method require you to have both proxy user/user and proxy password/password. And I only have half of them (proxy user & proxy password). So I'm afraid your method doesn't work for me....

Comment: So how would you like to login if you do not have the account username and password?

Answer (score 1):

In WinSCP, if you select the FTP protocol, you will have this option in the [*"Proxy Type"*](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_proxy):

```
USER %user@%proxyuser@%host
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin, I tried it but still can't log in. I've edited my question to include the log file. Thank you!

Comment: Show us FileZilla log for comparison (a real log file, not the message log from GUI).